# output won't shown up php

Tags: php, html

can someone please tell me why nothing is shown when opening this page?

```
<?php

include_once("functions.php");
// Process
$action = isset($_POST["action"]) ? $_POST["action"] : "";
if (empty($action)) 
{
    // Send back the contact form HTML
    $output = "<form action='#' style='display:none'>
               <label for='image'>upload:  </label>
               <input type='file' id='image' name='image' maxlength=50>";
}
echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: Why not use `if(isset($_POST["action"])) { ... }` directly?

Comment: maybe $_POST['action'] it's set

Comment: style='display:none' is the cause.

Comment: Also, you should add your `echo $output` to the `if` condition, otherwise you'll get an undefined variable notice when `$action` isn't empty

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use `if isset` directly and remove `style='display:none'` otherwise you will assign as property to not display to the form

```
include_once("functions.php");
// Process
if(!isset($_POST["action"]))
{
    // Send back the contact form HTML
    echo  "<form action='#'>
           <label for='image'>upload:  </label>
           <input type='file' id='image' name='image' maxlength=50>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<form style = "display:none">
```

This is preventing it from displaying.. Remove the style or replace it with `style = "display: block"` or whatever is your need.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
if (!empty($action))
```